# Check user's password is valid or not in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to check if a database user is valid.

I will allow users to change their passwords using the **ALTER** command, but before I do I want to validate their current password to make sure they are the who they say they are. Is it possible inside of pl/sql to take the user/password combination and check if it is valid or not?

Comment: I think this should answer your question...

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43086/how-to-change-a-user-password-while-checking-the-current-password-in-oracle

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the context of the question.  Normally, the user would already be logged in to the database before changing their password so you could use the fact that they are logged in as evidence that they know the current password.  If you want a user to change their password without being logged in, can you just use the `replace old_password` clause of the `alter user` command?

Comment: A question for others to clarify: wouldn't `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSION_USERID')` or `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY')` be good enough to get the name of whoever called your procedure ?? you don't really need to peek at password, just ask Oracle who the current user is authenticated as ...

Comment: If you don't validate the person at the time of the request, then you can't guarantee the validitee of the request itself.  As a sample Case study, Alice logs into the application in the morning, but gets called away from her desk, however, being forgetful this day she fails to lock her workstation.  While she's away Malice walks over to Alice's workstation and issues the password change request.  If you don't validate the change request by having Malice enter Alice's password, then the change request will go through when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Oracle database gives you an API for doing this.  One kludge you could use would be to use a loopback database link to check it.  Like this:

```
DECLARE
  p_username        VARCHAR2 (30) := 'MMCP';  -- Change to the user whose password you are validating
  p_test_password   VARCHAR2 (30) := 'NOT_MY_PASSWORD';  
  p_loopback_connection_string VARCHAR2(80) := 'ORCLQA';  -- Change this for your environment
BEGIN

  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[drop database link password_test_loopback]';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
  END;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'create database link password_test_loopback connect to "' || p_username || '" identified by "' || p_test_password || '" using ''' || p_loopback_connection_string || '''';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[SELECT * FROM dual@password_test_loopback]';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[drop database link password_test_loopback]';
  
  dbms_output.put_line('Password is good');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF SQLCODE = -1017 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Password is wrong');
  ELSE
    raise;
  END IF;
END;
```

More advanced options would be to find a way to use single signon / LDAP for your Oracle authentication.  Then, your problem becomes -- how do I validate a username/password in my LDAP dictionary, which is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Any database user can change its own password. This isn't something you can rule over. This is how it works "by design". Privileges for given user inside the database is another story. This is where you as the dba can rule.

```
sys@XE> create user a identified by a;

User created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
sys@XE> grant create session to a;

Grant succeeded.

sys@XE> @c a/a

a@XE> alter user a identified by b;

User altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
a@XE> @c a/b
a@XE>
```

Your application tool will have to have a module for password management.
Have a look at [Tom's answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:393018841461) to this: